how to add related product on shopify blog?
add related product on shopify blog without app
add related product code on blog
Where to add custom code?
Shopify Related Product Recommendations on blog : How to Add? Step-by-step Guide
Can we add related products in the blog page?
Show related products on shopify blog pages
Simple Add Related Products to Blog ...

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

You can not use the Product Recommendations section on Blog Post directly, because it is default and dynamic section. Instead of that you can use the [Featured Collection](https://prnt.sc/XUiWWpRTKReE) section. Where you can create the separate collection for blog post and also change the product sequence manually in that collection.

hi https://dongfutrade.com/blogs/camera-tips-and-reviews/best-4k-hdmi-on-camera-monitors-for-feelworld i want add related product in this blog, what can i do for edit add on code?

Normally you can create a meta filed and show in blog page then using that modify the template to show product. But this is a difficult way for merchant.
This app https://apps.shopify.com/easydisplay-product-showcase helps user to easily show product in blog page with image slider and video gallery.
Thank you

While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - From Review
